# Runaway argument? ! Paragraph ended before \inf@@get was complete with texshade

Tags: errors

I am trying to visualise the sample alignment file distributed with texshade but keep getting this error:

```
Runaway argument?

! Paragraph ended before \inf@@get was complete.
```

I am running it with the code and files provided in documentation since I couldn't get my own alignments to work, either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{texshade}
\begin{document}
\begin{texshade}{AQPpro.MSF}
\hideconsensus
\end{texshade}

\end{document}
```

I really don't understand what the problem is. I am running it on a Windows 10 laptop, TeX Live 2021. texshade version 1.26. A similar question was addressed some time ago but there seemed to be no concise solution.

Comment: looks like a bug, contact the author.